# Css inverting everything below an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter

Is it possible using css to have an element that inverts everything behind it such that anything that passes below the element will be inverted?

In the example I would like to the circle to be white while passing through the black square, but black otherwise.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.invert {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.move {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move linear 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  100% {
transform: translate(500px, 500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invert">

  </div>
  <div class="move">

  </div>
</div>
```

This needs to be structure agnostic, as in my actual implementation I am using a large number of randomly moving circles as a fixed background, I will not know when they will enter or exit a square, and the relation between circle and square will be different between pages

I've tried filter: invert(1), but it doesn't do what I need it to, I am also curious whether it could be done using svg filters.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`mix-blend-mode: difference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) with a white background on your `.invert` class:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.invert {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.move {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move linear 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
transform: translate(0,0);
  }
  100% {
transform: translate(500px, 500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invert">

  </div>
  <div class="move">

  </div>
</div>
```

The one caveat here is it can only invert elements that appear behind it. so if your `.move` object needs to be in the DOM after the inverter, you have to change the `z-index` of one or the other to get them to render correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried this already but may have done something wrong in my implementation, will try again tomorrow and mark the answer if it works.

Comment: @elliott_l The caveat there is important for `mix-blend-mode`, it can only interact with elements "behind" it in the DOM. `filter` only works on elements within, I'm not sure there's anything that will affect elements "in front".

Comment: Ok thank you I finally worked it out today, as well as fixing the z-index it turns out I also had to add blend mode difference to the base container of the invert element, not the invert element itself. I don't really know why but its working great now!